# Kik bot framework get Kik chat id

Tags: python, kik

I see in a lot of examples and in the docs this

```
       'chatId': 'b3be3bc15dbe59931666c06290abd944aaa769bb2ecaaf859bfb65678880afab'
```

I tried Googling but couldn't found anything except sites for finding people on kick. So is this the same as the API key i get when signing up. I'm using Python so in Node.JS maybe there won't show.

Comment: The `chatId` is the identification of the current conversation the message is coming from

Comment: How do you find it is my question i know that is uses to indentify the converstaion.

Comment: They are a field on the received message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `chatId` is a unique ID for every conversation your bot is in. The simplest way to handle them is to reply to messages with the same `chatId` they came in with. (i.e. if a message comes in with the `chatId` `foobar`, your response for it should include the `chatId` `foobar`).

See more at https://dev.kik.com/#/docs/messaging#sending-messages